# Writing from proc sql to file

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS and I need to write a single value into a file from proc sql but I am having so much trouble. Please see my code below.

```
data _null_;
FILE 'C:\MyFile.txt';

proc sql;
  select datepart(max(DateCreated))  into :dt from epx.temp;
  %put &dt date9.;
quit;

run;
```

I am running this code inside a MACRO in Precode and Postcode property of a job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `proc sql` statement is not valid inside the data step. Actually, SAS recognizes a `proc` as the end boundary of the data step so your data step contains only the `file` statement and does nothing.

The `file` statement affects the `put` statement, not the macro `%put` statement.

Without changing your general approach, you can do the following:

Put the formatted value into a macro variable then use the data step to write the value to your file.

```
proc sql;
select put(datepart(max(DateCreated)),date9.) into :dt from ext.temp;
quit;

data _null_;
  FILE 'C:\MyFile.txt';
  put "&dt";
run;
```

Another approach would be to do everything in the data step and avoid using macro variables altogether:

```
data _null_;
  file 'C:\MyFile.txt';
  set ext.temp end=eof;
  retain maxdate;
  if datepart(DateCreated) gt maxdate then maxdate=datepart(DateCreated);
  if eof then put maxdate date9.;
run;
```

Comment: Great! You are awesome!!! It is working just the way I want it to be. :-D Thank you so much! By the way, what is better, the 1st or the 2nd approach? The 1st approach is more understandable to me since I am from SQL. Hmm it looks like I have some reading assignment to do.